# How to use Parse() method from the UnitsNet nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget-package, units-of-measurement

I wanted to use [UnitsNet](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet) in my C# project and saw in the documentation that the authors are using their classes to parse units of measure from string like this:

```
var usEnglish = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Mass kg = Mass.Parse(usEnglish, "1.0 kg");
```

I wanted to use it the same way, so I installed the package in my project using nuget console by invoking:

```
Install-Package UnitsNet
```

and made sure that the reference is added in the project.

The problem is that I still can't see the Parse()/TryParse() methods on any of the unit types.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the documentation outdated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that the [UnitsNet](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet) documentation was a little bit ahead of the time.

The version I have been pulling from NuGet with

`Install-Package UnitsNet`

was **3.4.0**, and the changes I was trying to use, mentioned in the question were first introduced in version **3.5.0**.